# Magento’s Registry doesn't save my value

Tags: magento

My extension adds a block "before_body_end" of every page on my site, with an Observer set on "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" to pass a parameter (order_id) to my block in case a checkout was performed.

```
    $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('my_block');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setOrderId($orderId);
    }
```

This worked great, But now I've encountered some 'Rouge' extension that implements the whole checkout process without firing "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" and so my extension stopped working.
I've tried hooking on other events: 'checkout_submit_all_after' or 'sales_order_place_after' (required moving the configuration from "frontend" to "global" as I found documented somewhere),
But no matter what I've tried my block wasn't defined. (I guess it is a timing issue).
So I decided to try and set the order_id on a registry in the observer and get it in my block:

```
Mage::register('my_order_id', $orderId);
// Make sure it is set
Mage::log("Observer");
Mage::log(strftime('%c'));
Mage::log(Mage::registry('my_order_id'));
```

In my block I also print:

```
Mage::log("Block");
Mage::log(strftime('%c'));
Mage::log(Mage::registry('my_order_id'));
```

And my log gives:

```
2013-02-24T13:01:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Observer
2013-02-24T13:01:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Sun Feb 24 13:01:56 2013
2013-02-24T13:01:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): 60
2013-02-24T13:01:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Block
2013-02-24T13:01:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Sun Feb 24 13:01:57 2013
2013-02-24T13:01:57+00:00 DEBUG (7):
```

Any ideas how to pass the orderId to my block?

Comment: Are you sure that `$orderId` has a value? Have you tried setting the registry key to some explicit value?

Comment: I thought about that so that's why I printed the value back from the registry a couple of lines later, and indeed I got the print of 60.

Comment: @MarkSrulnik You can save it in session then and unset it after you retrieve it.

Comment: yes. set it using: Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyOrderId($orderId) and get it: $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyOrderId();

Comment: Great, Thanks!
This seemed to solve the issue, but I don't see an option to accept your answer.